# Not able to plot box plot separately

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot

I have lot of feature in data and i want to make box plot for each feature. So for that

```
import pandas as pd 
import seaborn as sns
plt.figure(figsize=(25,20))

for data in train_df.columns:
    plt.subplot(7,4,i+1)
    plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0.5, wspace = 0.5)
    ax =sns.boxplot(train_df[data])
```

I did this
and the output is
[image]

All the plot are on one image i want something like
[image]

( not with skew graphs but with box plot )
What changes i need to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, I cannot see where the `i` is coming from and also it's not clear how  `ax` was assigned.

Maybe try something like this, first an example data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

train_df = pd.concat([pd.Series(np.random.normal(i,1,100)) for i in range(12)],axis=1)
```

Set up `fig` and a flattened `ax` for each subplot:

fig,ax = plt.subplots(4,3,figsize=(10,10))
ax = ax.flatten()

The most basic would be to call `sns.boxplot` assigning `ax` inside the function:

```
for i,data in enumerate(train_df.columns):
                        sns.boxplot(train_df[data],ax=ax[i])
```

[image]